# Why am I getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named matplotlib.mathtext' when import matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a simple project where I am using matplotlib. I am not even calling it in the program, but am getting an error when trying to run the program. I am doing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.I am pretty sure the package is installed.

The full error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/sethmarks/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Users/sethmarks/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/Users/sethmarks/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "/Users/sethmarks/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "/Users/sethmarks/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 12, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.mathtext'
```

What do I need to do to correct this?

Comment: can you try running  `python -c "import matplotlib"` to see if its installed

Comment: If you are using matplotlib 3.0.0, try to upgrade matplotlib.